# How to disable iOS Google Mobile Ads SDK console logs?

Tags: ios, logging, admob

Whenever Google releases a new version of the Google Mobile Ads SDK, the current one spams the console with these:

```
<Google:HTML> You are currently using version x.y.z of the SDK. Please consider 
updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and 
bug fixes. The latest SDK can be downloaded from ****. 
A full list of release notes is available at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes.
```

These are output several times per ad load, and if you're actually trying to debug your app and move through different screens with different ads, then the console is a mess.

This is surely a great incentive to keep the SDK updated, but sometimes I would like to debug other issues that are higher in my priority list.

Comment: Are you using it with Firebase or not ?

Comment: No, does the Firebase logging setting affect the output of GMA?

Comment: Not sure, I think you're using an older version of the SDK. On newest versions that use Firebase, you can configure log level.

Answer (score -2):

I use Firefox and had a similar problem, I found a filter box inside the web console, this let me just show the logs from my scripts.